# A single unified account for all users on a single machine, while preserving separate credentials

Tags: rhel, users, login, administration

So this is more of a reverse-engineering question.

We have this machine at work, where anyone can login using ssh. `ssh johndoe@gateway01`. However! Once logged in, the user the person is logged in as is no longer `johndoe` but an account common for all the users, called `daq`.

If I do `cd ~johndoe`, it just redirects me to `~daq`.

And more interestingly, if I do `ssh daq@gateway01`, I get:

```
This account is currently not available.
Connection to gateway01 closed.
```

My question is how such a setup could possibly be achieved?

This works for every single user that is present in a list of users somewhere on the machine. This list is in a file called `gw_users`.

I noticed that in the same folder, there are some more files:

```
gw_passwd
gw_shadow
gw_group
```

Answer (score 2):

The "single account with many usernames, each with a separate password" effect could be achieved by having multiple lines in the `passwd` file with the same UID number. And if the line for username `daq` has its shell set as `/sbin/nologin`, it would result in exactly the same response to `ssh daq@gateway01` as you're seeing.

The `gw_passwd`, `gw_shadow` and `gw_group` files suggest that there may be a custom PAM configuration in effect on the `gateway01` system, possibly using those files as replacements for the standard `/etc/passwd`/`/etc/shadow`/`/etc/group` files, at least for `sshd`.

In other words, it might be enlightening to compare `/etc/pam.d/sshd` (or any files it references using `@include` directives) on that system to the same file(s) on another system that has the same Linux distribution in a default configuration.

The `gw_users` file containing the list of users might be used in scripts that maintain and/or generate the `gw_passwd` and other files, and/or the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file (which might have configured to enforce some additional restrictions to the gateway users).